# Need to use single quotes, double quotes, and variables in a string in R

Tags: r

Using the `car` package in R I need to use variables instead of hard coding the numbers

This works:

```
recode(rirecoded,"1:10='Low';11:20='Middle';21:30='High'")
```

This does not:

```
a=1
b=10
c=11
d=20
e=21
f=30
recode(rirecoded,"b:b='Low';c:d='Middle';e:f='High'")
```

I have tried using `cat()` but cannot get it to work

Comment: looks like you could use `cut` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:20,
                  y = sample(1:30, 20, replace = TRUE))


dat <- within(dat, {
                    z <- cut(y, c(1,10,20,30), 
                             labels = c('Low','Med','High'))
                    zz <- cut(y, c(a, b, d, f),
                              labels = c('Low','Med','High'))
})

> dat
    x  y    z   zz
1   1  6  Low  Low
2   2 29 High High
3   3 18  Med  Med
4   4  5  Low  Low
5   5  2  Low  Low
6   6 25 High High
7   7  8  Low  Low
8   8 20  Med  Med
9   9 18  Med  Med
10 10 16  Med  Med
11 11 30 High High
12 12 22 High High
13 13 24 High High
14 14 28 High High
15 15 17  Med  Med
16 16 25 High High
17 17  8  Low  Low
18 18 12  Med  Med
19 19 22 High High
20 20 26 High High
```

Answer (score 1):

R does not expand variable inside strings.  You have to construct the string explicitly with `paste`:

```
rirecoded <- sample(1:30)
recode.chr <- paste0(a,":",b,"='Low';",c,":", d,"='Middle';",e,":",f,"='High'")
recode(rirecoded, code.chr)
```

This produces:

```
#  [1] "High"   "Low"    "High"   "High"   "Low"    "Middle" "Middle" "Low"    "High"  
# [10] "Low"    "Low"    "High"   "Middle" "Middle" "Middle" "Middle" "Middle" "High"  
# [19] "Middle" "Middle" "High"   "Low"    "Low"    "High"   "Low"    "Low"    "Low"   
# [28] "High"   "High"   "Middle"
```

All this said, `cut` based solutions like rawr suggest seem simpler.